# Mac app for writing handwritten notes

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, notes.app, drawing

I would like to prepare hand-written notes (via One by Wacom tablet) for my educational purposes, therefore I would like to have a software which has

- ability to create infinite long (or big enough) canvas, where I can write using my tablet.

This is something similar to Notes or Word app, where one can write as much as they want, and pages keep on increasing.

Sketchbook seems to be promising, but resizing of canvas is not available in free version.
Krita seems to be very bulky for such simple tasks.

Can anyone suggest a free software which can fulfill this need?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[<sub>[image]</sub> **OneNote**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote/id784801555?mt=12&at=1001lwpF) has full pen support and provides a canvas to type or draw on.

[image: OneNote Draw ribbon]

Comment: This one is just awesome...

Answer (score 12):

I really like [Write](http://www.styluslabs.com/) by stylus labs. It can automatically add more space whenever you get to the bottom of the page and has a fair bit of wacom functionality, eg. use of the wacom eraser and pen buttons.

Comment: It seems it's no longer active the development.

Comment: Just tried it, Write is exactly what I wanted, it's working perfectly with MacOS 10.14.5 and and a 10 year old Intuos 3.

Comment: It's pretty good once the page is setup. However, interface could be simpler like mac Notes.

Comment: I tried today with macOS 10.13.6 and Intuos Draw (2015). It is working.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a few tools and ended up using GoodNotes.
I have been using it for 2 years, still happy with it.
A cool feature is that it sync's across Mac and iPad, and it offers apps on both iPad and Mac.